# Creating Persistant Symbolic Link -Linux

Tags: symlink, udev, devices, block-device

I have a cloud server, where a block device (/dev/xvdb1 with filesystem ext3) is attached .

I want to create a persistent symlink (/dev/test_link) which should always target to (/dev/xvdb1) using udev rules.

OS -> 16.04 ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se].  **;-)**  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Do you want to auto-mount the device to `/dev/test_link` because the description of what you're trying to accomplish looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Actually, I want to create a symlink under /dev using udev, persistently. the persistant symlink (/dev/test_link) should target the block device (/dev/xvdb1) which is on my LinuxAcademy cloud server which has ext3 filesystem.

Comment: That's a repeat of your request.  The question is: *What are you trying to accomplish here*: Learn about `udev` or trying to accomplish a task?

Comment: im trying to accomplish a task.

Comment: *Please help us help you:* [edit] your question and provide more details as it's hard to guess which task you're trying to accomplish.  For now, your question is **unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  ;-)**

Comment: I have edited the question, is it decode-able now?

Comment: Apparently, because you have an answer...   **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with using `udevadm monitor` when attaching your target device, or `udevadm info --name=/dev/xvdb1 --attribute-walk`, when already attached, to have a look at how udev sees your device. Than you can create udev rules which match only the special device. 
Also `blkid` would be a good starter, where you can see the ID of your device, for which you can than create udev rules. 
(Examples for rules can e.g. be found at https://wiki.debian.org/udev )

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I have created the symlink and I think its kinda work, could you please check my work? link: https://pastebin.com/JLL57dZx

Comment: I will not go through it completely, but one hint: the kernel may not always recognize the device as `xvdb1`. Depending on your attached devices it may e.g. be something like `xvda1` or `xvdc1` on another day of rebooting. Maybe `udevadm info dev/xvdb1` or `udevadm info dev/xvdb` will get you more/better possibilities to always pinpoint the correct device. There are many udev examples and beginner's guides out there to help you further :-)